# No boot into Unity after turning on automatic mount options for hard disk

Tags: boot, mount, disk, automount

My updated Ubuntu 15.4 desktop has a SSD drive (sda) and a hard disk (sdb). It boots from the SSD drive. Then I needed to click on the hard disk in order to mount it. Because I wanted my PC to automount I got into the "disks" utility and turned on “Automatic Mount Options”. I did not un-check “Show in user interface”. 
When I rebooted I only can get into Grub then command line. After login there are 10 error messages stating some paths starting with /var/lib/sudo/ can't be found and some paths starting with /usr/lib/update-notifyer are read only. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As usual askubuntu was just a waste of time, but at least I got some response this time. Thanks.

I understand it's difficult to get more experts to answers the many questions. I'll try to do my part helping others soon.

Problem was that my SSD was read only and I couldn't make it writable at startup. Tried an hour editing fstab with liveCD, and gave up. Tried the "repair reinstall" but made everything worse. Then just reinstalled my whole PC. Now all ok, even mounts my SATA HD automatically now.